# How to match anonymous object in mockk

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I am trying to verify a `logger::error` method called like this:

```
logger.error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, object {
    val field0 = field0Value
    val field1 = field1Value
})
```

I wonder how to match the anonymous object, something (type accurate) that would look around something like this:

```kotlin
verify {
    loggerMock.error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, match { it.field0 = theField0Value && it.field1 = theField1Value})
}
```

---

**Edit: degraded version fixed, see comment below**

I tried this degraded version:

```kotlin
verify {
    loggerMock.error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, any())
}
```

But I get a weird error code:

> Verification failed: call 1 of 1: DblLogger(loggerMock#2).error(eq(MY_ENUM_VALUE), any())) was not called.
> Calls to same mock:
>
> 1. DblLogger(loggerMock#2).error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, my.package.myClass$myFunction$memoryAddress>)

To me, `DblLogger(loggerMock#2).error(eq(MY_ENUM_VALUE), any()))` should've matched `DblLogger(loggerMock#2).error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, my.package.myClass$myFunction$memoryAddress>)`

Comment: I turned out `logger::error` had several overloads among which `fun error(tag: MyEnumType, message: String): Unit` and any() was thus inferred to String.

Writing `verify { loggerMock.error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, any<Any>() }` makes the degraded version work.

Comment: You can use any BUT that's pretty general. If yopu want to apply assertions to the parameter as well you can create a `slot<>` and use a `capture()`. It behaves like any BUT saves the parameter. After doing the actual (cut) call you can get the value and assert what was passed originally.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [custom matcher](https://mockk.io/#custom-matchers) to match any anonymous object with specific fields:

```
class SpecificObjectMatcher(
    private val expectedFields: Map<String, Any>
) : Matcher<Any> {
    override fun match(arg: Any?): Boolean {
        if (arg == null) return false
        if (arg::class.memberProperties.map { it.name }.toSet() != expectedFields.keys) return false
        return expectedFields.all { (name, value) -> arg.matchProp(name, value) }
    }

    private fun Any.matchProp(propName: String, value: Any?): Boolean {
        val field0Prop = this::class.memberProperties.firstOrNull { it.name == propName }
        return field0Prop != null && field0Prop.getter.call(this) == value
    }
}

inline fun <reified T> MockKMatcherScope.matchSpecificObject(
    vararg fields: Pair<String, Any>
): T = match(SpecificObjectMatcher(fields.toMap()))
```

The `match` function of the matcher with a given map of expected field names and values checks that

1. the `arg` is not null,
2. the member properties of the `arg` have exactly the names of the given fields to match, and
3. the values of the member properties are exactly the ones specified in the map of expected fields.

Then, for your example of a call

```
logger.error(MY_ENUM_VALUE, object {
    val field0 = field0Value
    val field1 = field1Value
})
```

we can write

```
verify {
    loggerMock.error(
       MY_ENUM_VALUE, 
       matchSpecificObject("field0" to field0Value, "field1" to field1Value)
    )
}
```

to verify quite precisely that the `error` function was called with an object consisting exactly of the specified fields.

Comment: Thanks! I tried using your implementation but I keep getting `Verification failed: call 1 of 1: DblLogger(loggerMock#4).error(eq(MY_ENUM_VALUE), my.package$SpecificObjectMatcher@memoryAddress) was not called.` while indeed having the method called with the expected values as anonymous object's fields...

Comment: That's a pity, maybe the wrong overload is mocked? You could try `matchSpecificObject<Any>(...)` to specify that the matcher should match an `Any` (like you did with `any<Any>()` before). If that doesn't work, it could be useful to debug the test to see why the matcher doesn't match, or if it is applied at all, or if the problem lies somewhere else.